# regEx replacing lazy multiple hits at once

Tags: regex, notepad++

I want to replace `abc xyz xyz` into `abc uvw uvw`. With this regEx search for `(abc)(.*?)(xyz)` and replace with `\1\2uvw` I get `abc uvw xyz` and need to repeat the procedure. I am testing in Notepad++. But even the "replace all" button does not replace all hits. Is there a way to replace all hits at once?

Comment: I don't understand the replacement.  What is wrong with just searching for literal `abc xyz xyz`?  Am I missing something?

Comment: I meant more general. E.g. abc asdj23 4235345 xyz 9834 3h erss 4 erss xyz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

**Find What**: `(?:\G(?!^)|abc)\s*\Kxyz`
**Replace With**: `uvw`

**Details**

- `(?:\G(?!^)|abc)` - end of the previous match or `abc`
- `\s*` - 0 or more (replace `*` with `+` to match 1 or more) whitespaces
- `\K` - match reset operator that discards all text matched so far
- `xyz` - `xyz` substring.

Note: in case there is a need to match these `xyz` across lines where `xyz` may appear at the start of a line, replace `\G(?!^)` with `\G(?!^(?<![\S\s]))` or `\G(?!^(?<!(?s:.)))`.

See the screenshot below:

[image]